# Making cross domain jquery ajax calls to Restful webservice?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am using Jquery Ajax calls to access REStful webservices as below. The webservice is hosted on different domain.

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "some url hosted on differnt domain",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(responseJson) {
        alert("json"+responseJson);


    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
          alert(err.Message);

    }
});
```

Am not sure whether it is not hitting the webservice.It is going to error block but no alert is displayed. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: `alert(xhr.responseText);` change in your error block. but is your cross domain url having set the required headers?

Comment: This is my cross domain url : http://10.4.100.111:8080/some-srv/rest/json/abc/123

Comment: Have you set the cross domain headers at your server side???

Comment: What does console.log(error) say? Usually for cross domain AJAX requests without the allowed-origin headers aren't problems with the AJAX calls themselves but the browser rejecting the responses from the server since they don't have the appropriate headers.

Comment: Where should i set the headers? Because i am using REStful services exposed by third party.

Comment: You need to see in your browser's console whether some error about CORS logged out or not.

Comment: Shall i write a controller and call the Rest service with in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to change the Header at you server side http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

Since it will cause forgery. For more of cors understanding http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Santhosh, to resolve it, shall i write a controller and call the restful service with in the controller?

Comment: What is the Server side technology you are using? that is considered here you got to add the header to it. Also you can look at you console it will show you that Get method failed.

Comment: I am using Spring 3 MVC.

Comment: You can set like following
`if(request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            String originHeader = request.getHeader("Origin");
 
            if(allowedOrigins.contains(request.getHeader("Origin")))
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
 
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
        }`

Comment: Santhosh, above logic should be in Restful services side? Because i dont have control over webservices. They are third party services. Am just using them using the URL.

Comment: You basically got to add `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: Santhosh, where should i add? Rest project side?

Comment: Yes You should add it to Rest Project Side

Comment: oh....without adding that can i call Rest service from Spring controller which resides in my project?

Comment: No you can't where as another option is from the Spring Controller load the view directly in model.

Comment: Can't call  a rest service from Spring controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make cross domain request just like that. It might cause cross-site forgery. Check this-

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Basically, to be able to do so, the server should allow you to do that. If you access some resource on a cross domain server. The server responds back with a list of allowed users for that resource. The browser reads that list. If you are not listed in that list then the browser won't show the resource to you.

**Solutions:**

1- You should have control of the server side.

2-you can try 'script' tags in HTML for your purpose. They are an exception to this. You can make cross-domain requests using 'script' tags and then parse the response as json.

3-[Jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) callbacks.

I haven't actually implemented in much detail because I have control over server side whenever I need. And, CDNs are open to all. So, you might want to do some reading now to figure out more.

Comment: Could you please give me example? atleast structure?

Comment: Okay..If i cannot call cross domain Rest service from my js file, then can i do it in the spring controller?

Comment: @user755806 you can't do it from your domain. You can't call from abc.com to xyz.com anyhow, until xyz.com allows abc.com

Comment: Even from server side?

Comment: @user755806 yes. Its an irritating problem I know. You got to kind a way out using the solutions I mentioned.